# How to plot a graph with different dimension?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a graph but there are lots of values in it. So i want to do is, on every specific x-axis value, I want 3 values from y-axis.I have a list for y-axis and I want my plotted values Like the 2nd biggest , median and the 2nd lowest values of y list.

When i try to plot it, it gives an error like this :ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (3,)

Here is my code:

```py
for i in range(0, 100):
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    Re = 0.1 * (1.1**i)  # 0,1<2017'e kadar Reynolds sayısı oluşturuyor.
    B = e ** (-0.08 * Re) * (2.5 * np.log(Re) + 5.25) + 8.5 * (1 - e ** (-0.08 * Re))  # B hesaplanıyor.
    C = 0.8+0.9*((e**(-0.08*Re)/(Re**2))+((1-e**(-0.08*Re))/(B**2)))**(-0.5)  # C=ub/u star
    F = 0.31*Re*e**(-0.1*Re)+1.8*e**(-0.88*d50/D)*(1-e**(-0.1*Re))  # Urmb,b/u star
    A = F/C   # Urmbs,b/Ub

    for j in range(10):
        n = np.random.normal(mean, sd, 100)

        Dcbss = 0.7*math.tan(fi/1.5) / (((1 + (abs(n[j])*A))**2)*(1+(1/2.5)*((abs(n[j])*F)**2)*math.tan(fi/1.5)))
        x.append(Re)
        y.append(Dcbss)
        y.sort()


    plt.xscale('log')
    z= [y[1], y[5],y [9]]

    plt.plot(x, z, 'ro', marker='.', markersize=0.5)


plt.show()
plt.close()
```

this is my values for example:

y=[0.02625,
0.03918,
0.06198,
0.10905,
0.14959,
0.16720,
0.16873,
0.20148,
0.20706,
0.23270]

x=[1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78,
1252.78

the list that I want to plot on the graph.
z=[
0.03918,
0.16720,
0.23270]

so how can I take those 3 values on every x-axis value and see only those 3 values on my graph ? Something like plot(x, z)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read how to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You supplied your code, which is good, but please also show the plot you are getting, as well as your desired output, so that we can help you better.

Comment: i dont have enough score to put my graph here. :(

Comment: no problem, atleast put the output of values you got for your variables which you used to make the graph.

Comment: Oky, some other improvements: I guess by `e` you mean the euler number? It's undefined. You can use `np.exp()` instead of `e**()`. other undefined variables are `d50 D mean sd fi Dcbss`. Make it so your code is executable without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` vector is obviously of size 10, and `z` vector of size 3. I assume you want to plot the same horizontal coordinate Re for your vector `z= [y[1], y[5],y [9]]`. If so, just replace

`plt.plot(x, z, 'ro', marker='.', markersize=0.5)`

by

`plt.plot([Re]*3, z, 'ro', marker='.', markersize=0.5)`